# vscode: Speed up navigation througe huge projects - intellisense etc

Tags: visual-studio-code

#### Objective

I've a huge vscode Project:

- 2 Mio Files
- 100+ GB.
- a lot of C-Files, but also build folders a lots of other irrelevant crap.

vscode is slow.
The project includes besides a lot of C/C++ files maybe in some parts cmake files, some codegen/glue-code, external headers, build scripts, external includes from SDK.

I want to use vscode to edit the code, not to compile or run it. The project consists besides the relevant c-files out of a lot of precompiled libs, helper tools, a huge amount of other files and images.

**I want to speed my vscode setup up.**

**How to tell the user supporting tools of vscode, where to set their focus?**

**Are there any other options to speed up vscode?**

#### Approach

My First Idea: "*Make vscode ignore of everything I do not need and tell the tools precisely on what to focus and which leave aside.*"

Is there a way to make vscode ignore all of such folders in search and in the c++ indexer, the tool which supports code navigation and syntax highlighting?

#### Clarification / Additional info

I do not have configured vscode. I do not know how. Most the time intellisens/code heighlighting / autocompletion etc. works fine and I can jump around in that code. How ever I've encountered some huge projects, where intellisens failed half or in total or took a lot of time to do so. I do want to set up an project properly. I do not know where to find such settings and most important, which behavior it affects:

- intellisense, please have a look only at folders ...
- actially, ignore everything below those folders
- take this single subfolder, but ignore everything around it.
- btw, there is an totally different location for SDK headers, could you also use code and header from there?

I do use vscode to edit the code, I do not use it to compile or debug the code.

*In short, I do not know which support tool (intellisense, c++ Extension, ???, ...) have which effect and where they can be configured. Like which vscode components make my life as easy as it is and how do I configure them?*

#### EDIT: List of installed Plugins

as from @user requested :). If cmake is known for eating resources, I could discard it. Is it mandatory for the intellisens stuff?
Could discard python too, if necessary.

- ms-vscode.cpptools

  - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options
- ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack
- ms-vscode.cpptools-themes

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools-themes
- alefragnani.bookmarks

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks
- twxs.cmake

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=twxs.cmake
- ms-vscode.cmake-tools

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools
- ms-python.python

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python
- ms-python.vscode-pylance

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance

Comment: Provide some details on how your c++ intellisense is set up. Is it [using CMake as the intellisense provider](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/how-to.md#set-up-include-paths-for-c-intellisense)?

Comment: thx for your reply, I strongly endited the question in hope to make my point. Are there any other ways to configure the project instead as a cmake driven Project?

Comment: List the IDs of your relevant, enabled extensions please and link to them on the visual studio marketplace.

Comment: @user thx for support, added links to used plugins :)